# Cannot open .po files: "Wrong type argument"

Tags: debugging

Whenever I try to open `.po` (Portable Object) files in emacs, I get a "find-file-noselect-1: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil" error and the file is not displayed. However, if I change the file extension to something else (like `.txt`), it opens in emacs fine. It seems as though emacs is trying to run the file because of its extension instead of just display it.

How can I get emacs to simply display `.po` files?

As a possibly relevant side note, whenever I execute `M-x po-mode`, it fails with the error "Cannot open load file: po-mode."

Comment: Does the error occur when you run emacs without loading you init file (`emacs -q`)?

Comment: Or, as a first step towards debugging the problem, you could `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before opening a .po file: this would show you the backtrace of where the error originates, which might give your readers a hint as to what's actually happening.

Comment: If po-mode doesn't load with `M-x po-mode`, that's almost certainly relevant. It sounds like po-mode isn't properly installed, or the installation is broken. It's not part of Emacs by default - how did you install it in the first place?

Comment: @JeanPierre: the error does still occur with `-q`. @wvxvw: with that toggle, I get `file-truename(nil)` as an error. @Tyler: I am on a shared system, so the sysadmin must have installed po-mode. Maybe the right answer it to ask them to reinstall it.

Comment: Yes, I would ask your admin to reinstall. Or just to remove the package - you can install it yourself without admin privileges. Emacs packages are stored in ~/.emacs.d/, so you should be able to manage your own packages there without your admin doing anything.